# Python AES decrypt string end with different char

Tags: python, char, aes

I have an input string and I'm encrypting it with MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT` and then decrypting it with python (not mysql `AES_DECRYPT`). I printed out some tests of the decrypted string:

```
print decrypt_string
print "%sxxx" % decrypt_string
print len(decrypt_string)
print self.toHex(decrypt_string)
```

When the input string length is 8, i.e. abcdefgh, the tests output will be:

```
abcdefgh
xxxdefgh
16
0x610x620x630x640x650x660x670x680x80x80x80x80x80x80x80x8
```

If input string length is 7, i.e. abcdefg:

```
abcdefg                                 
abcdefg                                 xxx
16
0x610x620x630x640x650x660x670x90x90x90x90x90x90x90x90x9
```

I found out that the ending char progressively decreases while the length of input string increases. Why is there a difference? If I use PHP AES encrypt instead of MySQL AES_ENCRYPT, the ending char will be 0x00. I am using use a third party [python AES lib](http://www.josh-davis.org/pythonAES).

Comment: try to encrypt/decrypt using your key with `m2secret` ([pip install m2secret](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2secret/))

Comment: I would advice against using a library which says *I recently became interested in Python and needed a "beginner" project to get me familiar with the basics of the language.* for cryptography purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your observation is that AES is a block cipher, which can only encrypt data in blocks of 128 bits (= 16 bytes). To do so, it is normally used with a mode of operation (to allow encrypting larger pieces of data), and a padding mode. It looks like your python decrypting function does the decrypting, but doesn't undo the padding, giving you this result.

You are using PKCS#5 padding, which will appends a number of bytes (at least one), all of the same value as this number, so the final length is a multiple of the block length.

- For your 8-bytes string, one needs to append 8 bytes, each of the value 8. ASCII 8 is the backspace character, which in your terminal moves the cursor one to the left (8 times), resulting in the `xxx` overprinting the `abc`.
- For your 7-bytes string, one needs to append 9 bytes, each of value 9. This is the horizontal tabulator, making your `xxx` appear quite on the right.

Either find out how to supply the right padding mode to your decryption function (it should have such an option), or remove the padding yourself: Check the last byte of decrypt_string, convert to a number (using its ASCII value), and take that many bytes from the end of the `decrypt_string`. You should also check that these all have the same value.
(You should do this first, before interpreting the output as a string, i.e. applying an encoding like UTF-8 or ASCII.)